# Are Microsoft Teams store third party apps developed like Teams custom apps?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I'm planning on deploying my (React) web app in a Microsoft Teams app. While it's clear that you can do that for custom apps used in your domain, I don't find any information about doing this for a third party app that would be available for everyone on the Teams store. Is this the same, apparently quite easy, process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in simple terms, it's basically the same. You can see more in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/publish . Some differences are:

1. You might want to test it better, if it's going to such a wide audience you can't control/engage with easily.
2. Security is probably more important when going to a public audience. For instance, you probably want to enable SSO - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview
3. Your graphics (icons) need to match specific guidelines
4. Your title, description and more are all vetted to make sure that they match certain guidelines.

All of this is documented in my first link above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer !
The web app is already used daily by +150k clients so we should be good for everything security/SSO related. Check the specific guidelines will be the bigger challenge in my mind.
Again : thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that and it be available for everyone on the Teams store. It's basically the same way of doing as for the custom apps used in your domain. Except the fact that you'll pass the validation process with a microsoft team.
I have validated my teams app with ReactJS  and ExpressJS and I used [this template](https://github.com/selego/teams-app-nodejs-boilerplate) for it. Much simpler to understand what is going on. It might be useful to you as well.